# Error: Incorrect Syntax Near '/'

Tags: sql, sql-agent-job

I am having problem with the `/` when executing a query below. I tried removing the `/`, then it gives me another error "incorrect syntax near """. I am getting confused what going on with my query. Thanks in advance

```
INSERT INTO Workers (TransManual, TransType, EmpNo, EmpName, TransDate, ScanIn, ScanOut, Basic, Overtime, Total, Remarks, Ocassion, Reason, Adjustment)
   SELECT 
      0 AS TransManual,
      1 AS TransType,
      EmpNo,
      EmpName,
      CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(CHAR(10), GETDATE(), 103), 103) AS TransDate,
      ''N/A'' AS ScanIn,
      ''N/A'' AS ScanOut,
      8 AS Basic,
      0 AS Overtime,
      8 AS Total,
      '''' AS Remarks,
      '''' AS Ocassion,
      '''' AS Reason,
      '''' AS Adjustment
   FROM Employees
   WHERE PayType = 1 
     AND Leave = 0
```

Comment: Don't you mean `'N/A'` instead of `''N/A''`. And if you don't want to insert anything, then better go with an empty string or `null`

Comment: do you need to store quotes as well in the field?

Comment: Was this copied from a dynamic SQL Statement? Looks like you need a global search and replace of `''` to `'`.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need 2 single quotes on each side of the N/A - 1 will do. `''N/A''` should be `'N/A'`. Your empty single quotes should also just be `''`. The only reason you'd have 2 single quotes inside of single quotes would be if you want a single quote to be placed into the database record.

Answer (score 2):

i think you are going wrong here

```
''N/A'' AS ScanIn,
 ''N/A'' AS ScanOut,
```

if you want to insert `N/A` then it you should write it as

```
'N/A' AS ScanIn,
'N/A' AS ScanOut,
```